# problem while installing wrtc on heroku app

Tags: node.js, npm, heroku

I have been trying to push my node app to heroku but it keeps failing because I am useing wrtc. I have tried to push the app without including wrtc and it went perfect but I do need wrtc libarary actually. So anyways I am getting this error.
Now I have tried to use other npm and node versions but it didn't change anything as well.

````
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Using buildpack: heroku/nodejs
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote:        
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote:        
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  12.18.4
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
remote:
remote:        Resolving node version 12.18.4...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 12.18.4...
remote:        Using default npm version: 6.14.6
remote:        
remote: -----> Restoring cache
remote:        Cached directories were not restored due to a change in version of node, npm, yarn or stack
remote:        Module installation may take longer for this build
remote:        
remote: -----> Installing dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules
remote:        npm ERR! node-pre-gyp not accessible from wrtc
remote:
remote:        npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote:        npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.2u56o/_logs/2021-12-06T20_03_06_668Z-debug.log
remote: 
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:        
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:
remote:        If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
remote:        https://help.heroku.com/
remote:
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to laststream.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/laststream.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined).```








Heeeelp please
````

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add your `package.json`.

Comment: I actually was able to solve this just by installing node-pre-gyp as a dependency. Thanks :)